# How can i give margin to divs that i got with foreach

Tags: html, css

I want to check if give margin to divs that I got with foreach

```
echo "<div id='NotificationsDispl'><a href='main.php?u=".$initiator."'>
        <img title='".$initiator."' src='../img/".$_SESSION['pr']."' id='FromsPP'></a>
        <a id='NotificationFrom' href='main.php?u=$initiator'>".$initiator." Sent you a friend request</a>
        <form class='submitForm Rejecat' method='post' onSubmit='return false;' >
          <input value='Reject' type='submit' name='Reject' id='Reject'>
        </form>
        <form onSubmit='return false;' class='submitForm Accepta' method='post'>
            <input name='Accept' type='submit' id='Accept' value='Accept'>
        </form>
    </div>";
```

I have got this css code

```
#NotificationFrom{
    margin-left: 125px;
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 102;
    color: black;
    margin-top:15px;
}
#NotificationsDispl{
    display: list-item;
    margin-top: 11px;
    padding: 25px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Have you made use of developer tools from the browser to see why the css style is not working?

Comment: @Gonzalo Nope how do you do that?

Comment: It changes in every browser, `F12` probably open it.

Comment: @Gonzalo Oh yes i thought it's name was inspect element.Yes but it does not give any css errors to me

Comment: But when you select the div, is there any style rule? are styles applied to them?

Comment: @Gonzalo Yes there is

Comment: Could you show what you see in that situation?

Comment: @Gonzalo do you need #NotificationsDispl or #NotificationFrom

Comment: Well if this code generates multiple `div`s, you shouldn't be using an id with them. Consider classes, or just general `div` styling

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<div class='notif_displ' id='NotificationsDispl'>

.notif_displ{
margin-top: 11px !important;
}
```

Comment: No it gives the same result.

Comment: No it is not working.I think the problem is as soon as delete position absolute it works normal but when new notification comes div goes down

Comment: the problem could be the responsiveness of your page, I can't tell as i don't have access to your full code.

Comment: Yes if you want i can write some parts.

Answer (score 0):

As per the `jsfiddle`, I tired copying your code.

```
<div id='NotificationsDispl'><a href='main.php?u=".$initiator."'>
    <img title='".$initiator."' src='../img/".$_SESSION['pr']."' id='FromsPP'></a>
    <a id='NotificationFrom' href='main.php?u=$initiator'>".$initiator." Sent you a friend request</a>
    <form class='submitForm Rejecat' method='post' onSubmit='return false;' >
      <input value='Reject' type='submit' name='Reject' id='Reject'>
    </form>
    <form onSubmit='return false;' class='submitForm Accepta' method='post'>
        <input name='Accept' type='submit' id='Accept' value='Accept'>
    </form>
</div>



#NotificationFrom{
        margin-left: 125px;
        position: absolute;
        text-decoration: none;
        z-index: 1;
        color: black;
        margin-top:15px;
    }
    #NotificationsDispl{
        display: list-item;
        margin-top: 11px;
        padding: 25px;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

Check this link https://jsfiddle.net/p025mpbg/

Therefore, if CSS changes are not being applied,

Do the following:

**1. Inspect element on the site by right clicking or pressing f12**

**2. Check for styling. There must be a CSS from different file that you are using is overwritten and your changes are not being applied.**